# Segmentation Fault - Strassen's Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, strassen

I'm a newbie and I have tried to implement Strassen's algorithm to multiply two NxN matrices. I'm currently working on even dimensions. I'm getting a segmentation fault for values of N greater than 4.

After debugging I figured that the segmentation fault is encountered before the first call to the multiply function and immediately after displaying the two matrices.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks very much!

```
#define N 8
typedef struct matrix
{
    int rs;
    int re;
    int cs;
    int ce;
    int a[N][N];
}matrix;

void display(matrix);
matrix multiply(matrix, matrix);
matrix add(matrix, matrix);
matrix sub(matrix, matrix);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    matrix m1;
    matrix m2;
    matrix result;

    printf("Enter the values for matrix one: ");
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N ; j++)
            scanf(" %d", &m1.a[i][j]);
    }

    printf("Enter the values for matrix two: ");    
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N ; j++)
            scanf(" %d", &m2.a[i][j]);
    }

    m1.rs = m2.rs = m1.cs = m2.cs = 0;
    m1.re = m2.re = m1.ce = m2.ce = N-1;

    display(m1);
    display(m2);
    **I believe the first call to multiply is not executed and there's a segmentation fault here.**
    result = multiply(m1, m2);

    display(result);

}

void display(matrix mat)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=mat.re;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=mat.ce;j++)
            printf("%d ", mat.a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
matrix multiply(matrix m1, matrix m2)
{

    int dimension = m1.re - m1.rs + 1;

    matrix result;
    result.rs = result.cs = 0;
    result.re = result.ce = dimension -1;

    if (dimension <=2)
    {
        matrix m3 = m1;

        int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

        a = m1.a[m1.rs][m1.cs];
        b = m1.a[m1.rs][m1.cs + 1];
        c = m1.a[m1.rs + 1][m1.cs];
        d = m1.a[m1.rs + 1][m1.cs + 1];

        e = m2.a[m2.rs][m2.cs];
        f = m2.a[m2.rs][m2.cs + 1];
        g = m2.a[m2.rs + 1][m2.cs];
        h = m2.a[m2.rs + 1][m2.cs + 1];

        m3.a[m3.rs][m3.cs] = a*e + b*g;
        m3.a[m3.rs][m3.cs+1] = a*f + b*h;
        m3.a[m3.rs+1][m3.cs] = c*e + d*g;
        m3.a[m3.rs+1][m3.cs+1] = c*f + d*h;

        return m3;
    }
    else
    {
        matrix A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
        matrix P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7;
        matrix R1, R2, R3, R4;

        A = B = C = D = m1;
        E = F = G = H = m2;

        A.rs = m1.rs;
        A.re = m1.re/2;
        A.cs = m1.cs;
        A.ce = m1.ce/2;

        B.rs = m1.rs;
        B.re = m1.re/2;
        B.cs = (m1.ce/2)+1;
        B.ce = m1.ce;

        C.rs = (m1.re/2)+1;
        C.re = m1.re;
        C.cs = m1.cs;
        C.ce = m1.ce/2;

        D.rs = (m1.re/2)+1;
        D.re = m1.re;
        D.cs = (m1.ce/2)+1;
        D.ce = m1.ce;

        E.rs = m2.rs;
        E.re = m2.re/2;
        E.cs = m2.cs;
        E.ce = m2.ce/2;

        F.rs = m2.rs;
        F.re = m2.re/2;
        F.cs = (m2.ce/2)+1;
        F.ce = m2.ce;

        G.rs = (m2.re/2)+1;
        G.re = m2.re;
        G.cs = m2.cs;
        G.ce = m2.ce/2;

        H.rs = (m2.re/2)+1;
        H.re = m2.re;
        H.cs = (m2.ce/2)+1;
        H.ce = m2.ce;

        P1 = multiply(A, sub(F, H));    
        P2 = multiply(add(A, B), H);    
        P3 = multiply(add(C, D), E);
        P4 = multiply(D, sub(G, E));
        P5 = multiply(add(A, D), add(E, H));
        P6 = multiply(sub(B, D), add(G, H));
        P7 = multiply(sub(A,C), add(E, F));


        R1 = add(add(P5, P6), sub(P4,P2));
        R2 = add(P1, P2);
        R3 = add(P3, P4);
        R4 = sub(sub(add(P1,P5), P3), P7);

        int m1_i, m1_j;
        int i,j;

        for(m1_i=R1.rs, i=0; m1_i<=R1.re; m1_i++, i++)
        {
            for(m1_j=R1.cs, j=0; m1_j<=R1.ce; m1_j++, j++)
                result.a[i][j] = R1.a[m1_i][m1_j];
        }

        for(m1_i=R2.rs, i=0; m1_i<=R2.re; m1_i++, i++)
        {
            for(m1_j=R2.cs, j=dimension/2; m1_j<=R2.ce; m1_j++, j++)
                result.a[i][j] = R2.a[m1_i][m1_j];
        }

        for(m1_i=R3.rs, i=dimension/2; m1_i<=R3.re; m1_i++, i++)
        {
            for(m1_j=R3.cs, j=0; m1_j<=R3.ce; m1_j++, j++)
                result.a[i][j] = R3.a[m1_i][m1_j];
        }

        for(m1_i=R4.rs, i=dimension/2; m1_i<=R4.re; m1_i++, i++)
        {
            for(m1_j=R4.cs, j=dimension/2; m1_j<=R4.ce; m1_j++, j++)
                result.a[i][j] = R4.a[m1_i][m1_j];
        }

        return result;
    }
}

matrix add(matrix m1, matrix m2)
{
    matrix result;
    int m1_i, m1_j, m2_i, m2_j, i, j;

    result.rs = result.cs = 0;
    result.re = result.ce = m1.re - m1.rs;

    for(m1_i = m1.rs, m2_i = m2.rs, i=0; m1_i<=m1.re;  m1_i++, m2_i++, i++)
    {
        for(m1_j=m1.cs, m2_j = m2.cs, j=0; m1_j<=m1.ce; m1_j++, m2_j++, j++)
            result.a[i][j] = m1.a[m1_i][m1_j] + m2.a[m2_i][m2_j];
    }

    return result;
}

matrix sub(matrix m1, matrix m2)
{
    matrix result;
    int m1_i, m1_j, m2_i, m2_j, i, j;

    result.rs = result.cs = 0;
    result.re = result.ce = m1.re - m1.rs;

    for(m1_i = m1.rs, m2_i = m2.rs, i=0; m1_i<=m1.re;  m1_i++, m2_i++, i++)
    {
        for(m1_j=m1.cs, m2_j = m2.cs, j=0; m1_j<=m1.ce; m1_j++, m2_j++, j++)
            result.a[i][j] = m1.a[m1_i][m1_j] - m2.a[m2_i][m2_j];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where is `multiply` defined? Please show us the code for `multiply` as it looks like the problem is in there. We cannot solve your problem without having the code that causes your problem.

Comment: Hi, Are you sure that & of an array entry is supported by your compiler:
scanf(" %d", &m1.a[i][j]); Try int temp; scanf(" %d", &temp);m1.a[i][j]=temp;

Comment: @FUZxxl I didn't include the code for multiply as the debugger showed an error before the first function call. I've included it now.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Colette Yes I'm fairly positive

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette `&m1.a[i][j]` should work, that's completely fine.

Comment: @RanganathaRao My compiler warns that there is an array access out of bounds in `multiply()`. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: @FUZxxl I performed a dry run and everything seemed fine. I'll do it again. But are you sure the first call to multiply is executed? Because I included some print statements and it didn't work.

Comment: @RanganathaRao I debugged myself and it looks like your code enters an infinite recursion in `multiply()`. Something is fishy with the way you compute the dimensions for your submatrices.

Comment: @RanganathaRao What “didn't work?” Please never ever say “it didn't work.” That's not an error description. Where did you add print statements and what happened?

Comment: `B.cs = (m1.ce/2)+1;` looks wrong. I would start by rewriting all the `N-1` and `(for; i <=N-1; ) {}` into the `N` form : `for( ; i < N; ){}`

Comment: @FUZxxl I included a print statement right before the first call to multiply. The program crashed without executing the print statement.

Comment: @RanganathaRao Did your print statement print a complete line? Because if you just did `printf("foo")` without a `\n` in there, then it's clear why this wasn't printed (because of line buffering).

Comment: Also, the debugger clearly shows that `multiply` is entered and that the program crashes after calling `multiply` recursively for the 100th or so time.

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes, that was the issue. Thanks for your input. I'll look into the infinite recursion.

Comment: @RanganathaRao Let me turn this into an answer so future people can see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is entering an infinite recursion in `multiply()`, gdb shows a stack trace like this:

```
#0  0x0000000000400899 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:60
#1  0x0000000000400fc7 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:140
#2  0x0000000000401584 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:142
#3  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#4  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#5  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#6  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#7  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#8  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#9  0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#10 0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
(...)
#421 0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#422 0x0000000000401859 in multiply (m1=..., m2=...) at b.c:143
#423 0x000000000040067c in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at b.c:43
```

This likely causes a stack overflow which causes the crash you observe. Here is the code around line 143:

```
   140          P1 = multiply(A, sub(F, H));    
   141          P2 = multiply(add(A, B), H);    
   142          P3 = multiply(add(C, D), E);
   143          P4 = multiply(D, sub(G, E));
   144          P5 = multiply(add(A, D), add(E, H));
   145          P6 = multiply(sub(B, D), add(G, H));
   146          P7 = multiply(sub(A,C), add(E, F));
```

I suspect the logic you use to compute the sizes of the subarrays is faulty. Further digging shows that `m2` has *negative* dimensions in the recursive calls, you should do some further debugging to find out what exactly went wrong.

Another issue my compiler warns about is this:

```
b.c: In function 'multiply':
b.c:166:28: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
                 result.a[i][j] = R2.a[m1_i][m1_j];
                            ^
b.c:178:28: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
                 result.a[i][j] = R4.a[m1_i][m1_j];
```

Here are the corresponding source lines:

```
   163          for(m1_i=R2.rs, i=0; m1_i<=R2.re; m1_i++, i++)
   164          {
   165              for(m1_j=R2.cs, j=dimension/2; m1_j<=R2.ce; m1_j++, j++)
   166                  result.a[i][j] = R2.a[m1_i][m1_j];
   167          }
...
   175          for(m1_i=R4.rs, i=dimension/2; m1_i<=R4.re; m1_i++, i++)
   176          {
   177              for(m1_j=R4.cs, j=dimension/2; m1_j<=R4.ce; m1_j++, j++)
   178                  result.a[i][j] = R4.a[m1_i][m1_j];
   179          }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate the effort. I'm working on it.

Comment: You're right. My sub matrices were ill formed. Thanks very much!

Comment: @RanganathaRao It was a pleasure to me.